# How to add an event on sliding

Tags: javascript, slider, dom-events

To begin with I am only learning web dev, that's why my question might be simple for some users, I hope so:)

I wrote the snake game in canvas, it works well with WASD buttons but I caught an idea to adapt it for mobile. I added some buttons but there is still a problem that it is very uncomfortable to use them. I decided to try slide events, but I really couldn't find any information about slide events. How can I add event listeners on slides? I mean that I need to add an event listener to change snake's direction by finger sliding.

Comment: I don't think there is a "slide" event in js, but there is a touch event for smart-phone devices, see this video [touch-drag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhF1m6Pgj4A) , I hope the video can inspire you to come up with a smart solution :) Maybe you could calculate the x and y coordinates of the **touch-drag** and then do something with that :)

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: If you make a "invisible scroll bar" in css and then if the user "slides" it will emit a "scroll-event" and you can handle it as a "slide"-event. :)

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: [Detecting a swipe (left, right, top or down) using touch](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml) :)

Comment: @AugustJelemson Thank you guys, i think i should use jquery scroll and swipe to change direction, i will try it in few hours

Comment: @ArtyomBelsky ok, good luck! :) and please share your solution